# Using delegates to call async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I am calling an `async` api to get details.
The target `api` endpoint can change and want to pass it as dynamic function.

Since the pagination of details is same for all apis, how can we make it as `delegate` function with `async return value?`

```
private async Task<List<Items>> GetItemsAsync(HttpClient client, string arg1)
{
    var totalResults = new List<Items>();
    int skip = 0, resultsCount = 1;

    while (resultsCount != 0)
    {
        var results = await GetItems(client, arg1, skip);
        if (results != null)
        {
            totalResults.AddRange(results);
            resultsCount = results.Count;
            skip += resultsCount;
        }
        else
        {
            resultsCount = 0;
        }
    }

    return totalResults;
}

private async Task<List<Users>> GetUsersAsync(HttpClient client, string arg1)
{
    var totalResults = new List<Users>();
    int skip = 0, resultsCount = 1;

    while (resultsCount != 0)
    {
        var results = await GetUsers(client, arg1, skip);
        if (results != null)
        {
            totalResults.AddRange(results);
            resultsCount = results.Count;
            skip += resultsCount;
        }
        else
        {
            resultsCount = 0;
        }
    }

    return totalResults;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
private async Task<List<T>> Get<T>(Func<Task<int, int, List<T>>> factory, int skip, int take)
{
    var totalResults = new List<T>();
    var resultsCount = 1;

    while (resultsCount != 0)
    {
        var results = await factory(skip, take);
        if (results != null)
        {
            totalResults.AddRange(results);
            resultsCount = results.Count;
            skip += resultsCount;
        }
        else
        {
            resultsCount = 0;
        }
    }

    return totalResults;
}

public Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string arg1)
{
    return Get<User>((skip, take) => GetUsers(httpClient, arg1, skip, take), 0, 10);
}

public Task<List<Item>> GetItemsAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string arg1)
{
    return Get<Item>((skip, take) => GetItems(httpClient, arg1, skip, take), 10, 10);
}
```

In some cases the following might also be enough, but not in your case evidently, because it seems you need to do something more with the skip argument:

```
private async Task<List<T>> Get<T>(Func<Task<List<T>>> factory)
{
    ...
}

public Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string arg1)
{
    return Get<User>(() => GetUsers(httpClient, arg1, 0, 10));
}

public Task<List<Item>> GetItemsAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string arg1)
{
    return Get<Item>(() => GetItems(httpClient, arg1, 10, 10));
}
```

Comment: missed out small detail. I need to pass `skip` argument from the delegate, which is where I am struggling